# How to you start using cloud in a non-tech savvy company?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, billing, google-cloud-billing

How could a company's first technical employee (or a consultant) integrate cloud service costs into the company budget? My thinking is that when you build "serverless" or "autoscaling" services the company may ask

> How much will this cost? $10/month? $1,000/month?

and it seems unclear how to manage those costs.

If we just do an example. Let's say I build a Heroku or Cloud Run (GCP) hosted dashboard, or a simple web app using Firebase. Who pays for it? I don't want company tools to run out of my credit card for obvious reasons.

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not about a practical programming problem as outlined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have technical solution of your problem.

Then, find out the size of your data in each request. How much bandwidth you will use? Where you will store the data? How much CPU you will use? etc.
Based on this extrapolate your cost for whole month.

Based on that you can use GCP calculator https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator

Comment: Hi there. I appreciate the answer, but I think I misworded the question. Suppose I know that it will cost $20-$50 pm; who do you think should be responsible for paying this in the company?

I suppose I could set up an organization...

My goal is to build something and not have to be there to maintain it / settle billing.

Comment: hi. May be you are looking for budget and alerts https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets 
Who should settle the billing is internal to company. May be account dept can do it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to start with one of the major cloud providers free plans, for example in AWS you can open [free account](https://aws.amazon.com/free/?all-free-tier.sort-by=item.additionalFields.SortRank&all-free-tier.sort-order=asc) for 12 month and you can start building your serverless code, create api, store data and much more. after getting confidence with your solution you can present it to your company and decide later if they want to continue with payable usage or not.

Comment: **Google Cloud Platform provide free access** [90-day, $300 Free Trial](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#free-trial). In addition, some GCP services are part of [Free tier](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#free-tier) and you can use them for free. **This question about GCP**, not AWS.

Comment: It was an example for one of the major cloud providers. Thank you for elaborate it with Google free tier.